# ifelse with multiple outputs

Tags: r, if-statement, row

Is it possible to obtain multiple outputs with `ifelse`?
I would like to create a variable `ExpectedVariable` with either 0s or 1s.
If `VariableA` has a value of 0, then I need `ExpectedVariable` to be 0 for the current row and for the previous row. If `VariableA` has a value of 1, then I need `ExpectedVariable` to be 1.

I was thinking of something like this (which as it is doesn't work):

```
 mydata$ExpectedVariable <- ifelse(mydata$VariableA == 0, (mydata$ExpectedVariable & lag(mydata$ExpectedVariable) <- 0), 1)
```

Example:

```
         VariableA    ExpectedVariable
row1     1            1
row2     1            1
row3     1            1
row4     1            1
row5     1            1
row6     1            0
row7     0            0
row8     1            1
row9     1            0
row10    0            0
row11    1            1
row12    1            1
row13    1            0
row14    0            0
```

Comment: What value do you want to have for `ExpectedVariable` if the current row has a 0 in `VariableA` but a 1 in the previous row?

Comment: It is very easy and doesn't hurt much to provide your example data with `dput(mydata)`.

Comment: If `df$VariableA == x` then `x[which(x == 0) - 1)] <- 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can think about your problem is that `ExpectedVariable` will equal zero if either of two conditions are met (current value of `VariableA` is zero, or the *lead* of `VariableA` is zero). In other words, instead of thinking of multiple *outputs*, think of multiple *conditions*, which `ifelse()` can easily do. Then we can accomplish this with any sort of shifting function.

Using `data.table::shift()`:

```
expected_df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
         VariableA    ExpectedVariable
row1     1            1
row2     1            1
row3     1            1
row4     1            1
row5     1            1
row6     1            0
row7     0            0
row8     1            1
row9     1            0
row10    0            0
row11    1            1
row12    1            1
row13    1            0
row14    0            0")

rownames(expected_df) <- NULL

mydata <- data.frame(VariableA = expected_df$VariableA)
mydata$ExpectedVariable <- ifelse(mydata$VariableA == 0
                                  | data.table::shift(mydata$VariableA,
                                                      type = 'lead') == 0,
                                  0, 1)
all.equal(mydata, expected_df)

[1] TRUE
```

Using `dplyr::lead()`

```
mydata$ExpectedVariable <- ifelse(mydata$VariableA == 0
                                  | dplyr::lead(mydata$VariableA) == 0,
                                  0, 1)

all.equal(mydata, expected_df)

[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick :

```
df$expectedVariable[df$VariableA == 1] <- 1
df$expectedVariable[df$VariableA == 0] <- 0
df$expectedVariable[which(df$VariableA == 0) - 1] <- 0
```

Or with the 2 last lines in one :

`df$expectedVariable[c(which(df$VariableA == 0), which(df$VariableA == 0) - 1)] <- 0`